# struts2 ajax redirect

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo

i develop a app that is built with struts2+tiles+dojo (for the ajax part), and i have the following demand: At every 2 seconds i have to check a table from the DB, if certain conditions are met, i have to redirect the user to a special page.
The way that i solved this problem was creating a struts2 actions which`s check the table and render as a response something like :

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <html> 
    <body>      
       <script> 
         window.location= '<s:property value="url"/>';
       </script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

and this page is accesed via a ajax call like:

```
<sx:div href="%{ajaxUrl}" 
    updateFreq="1200" 
    cssStyle="float:right"
    id="live" 
    loadingText="Loading..." 
    executeScripts="true"
    parseContent="false">
</sx:div>
```

and this is how i accomplish the redirect.
I`m sure that there has to be an more elegant and optimized solution.
Any ideeas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the struts2-json-plugin on the action which is the target of ajaxUrl. I don't use the sx tags, I just use JS (with jQuery, the normal library not using any struts2 plugin).  Any ways use JS to asynchronously call your action every 2 seconds with JS (or framework of choice) and you will get back the url as a json string, and you will then redirect to that new url if the string is not empty (or you could return back many variables perhaps, perhaps containing some of the conditions found in the DB and showing them on the page and redirect according to those status variables).

Comment: Hi Quaternion, seems a good idea to remove the sx tags because i hate them :), i`ll give a try with you solution and came back to post the results/mark answer as accepted.